# Improper integral inequality including the golden ratio and the Sophomore's dream

Tags: inequality, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, golden-ratio

It's an inequality I found nice let me propose it :

Let $0\leq x$ then we have :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(x^{-x}\right)dx<\phi=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}{2}\quad (I)$$

---

My attempt :

First of all I recall two facts :

### Fact 1

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{-x}\ dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-n}$$

---

### Fact 2:

Let $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ then we have :

$$\sin\left(x\right)\leq x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{x^{5}}{5!}$$

---

Unfortunately it works on $J=[0,1]$ not on $[0,\infty]$ so see [The "natural" Sophomore's Dream integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-x}\ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268295/the-natural-sophomores-dream-integral-int-0-infty-x-x-dx) wich is a useful link .

Edit : for $x\in(1,\infty)$ it seems we have :

$$\left(e^{\left(-\frac{e}{\left(e-1\right)^{2}}\left(\left(\ln\left(x^{2}+e-1\right)\right)-e^{-1}\right)^{2}\right)}e^{\left(e^{-\left(1\cdot0.85+0.15\cdot\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}\right)\geq x^{-x}\quad(G)$$

---

Edit 2:

To show $(G)$ we first take the logarihthm on both side and then use the very well know expansion via Taylor's series of logarithm and exponential .Currently I don't see better . Then we have :

### $$\int_{0}^{2}\sin\left(x^{-x}\right)dx+\int_{2}^{\infty}\left(e^{\left(-\frac{e}{\left(e-1\right)^{2}}\left(\ln\left(x^{2}+e-1\right)-e^{-1}\right)^{2}\right)}e^{e^{-\left(0.85+\frac{0.15}{x}\right)}}\right)dx<\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}{2}$$

---

Edit 3 : It seems we have on $(1,2)$ :

### $$e^{-\left(\frac{x^{0.48}\left(x-1\right)}{2^{0.48}}\right)\cdot2\ln\left(2\right)}>x^{-x}$$

Edit 4:

It seems we have on $(0,1)$ :

### $$e^{\left(1.02-0.02\cdot\frac{2x}{x+1}-x\right)\cdot2^{0.6}x^{0.6}\ln\left(2\right)}> x^{-x}$$

And :

For $2\leq x\leq 6$ :

### $$e^{\left(-\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{93}{100}}x^{0.5}\cdot2^{0.5}\ln\left(2\right)\right)}\geq x^{-x}$$

---

Edit 5:

Following an answer due to user Michael Rozenberg here ( [Which is greater $\frac{13}{32}$ or $\ln \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713384/which-is-greater-frac1332-or-ln-left-frac32-right?noredirect=1&lq=1) ) we have for $0<x<1$ :

### $$e^{-x\left(x-1\right)\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}+x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}> x^{-x}$$

---

Question :

How to show the inequality $(I)$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "let $0\leq x\leq 1$" ? The range of integration is $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @K.defaoite my bad let me corrects it !

Comment: This is a very interesting inequality. I am having trouble bounding $x^{-x}$ tightly because it shrinks to zero so fast.

Comment: I presume you mean $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yes !

Comment: The integral is approximately $1.612215$ and that happens to be less than the golden ratio. But that looks like a pure coincidence to me, I doubt that there is a connection between the integral and the golden ratio.

Comment: I propose $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^{-x})dx < 10 \cos(5 \pi/17) \cos(12 \pi/29)$.

Comment: Following @Martin R;, I propose (from ISC) $$\left(\frac{j_{0,1}}{\log (\pi )}\right){}^{\text{Cahen}}=1.6122153458277$$ in error of $1.94 \times 10^{-7}$.

Comment: @MartinR It's not really pretty...

Comment: $$\phi -\frac{1}{100} I_0(2){}^{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{12}\right)-C}$$ is in error of $1.03\times 10^{-9}$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=express+1.6122151518051230319711275754558425169091870476066+through+GoldenRatio

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Wolfram alpha is saying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n} \approx 1.29$.

Comment: @mathworker21 What do you mean ? Your result is correct .

Comment: Can I evaluate the integral and use the decimal answer to prove it is smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here will be my attempt at evaluating the integral. We will use this [sine](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/06/01/02/01/) series to evaluate with the help of this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mradf4o6e3). The sine expansion actually works which simplfies the problem into a [generalized tetration integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135449/area-under-x-x-over-its-real-domain-what-is-another-non-integral-form-of). We can interchange the sum and integral term by term:

$$\mathrm{I=\int_{\Bbb R^+}sin(x^{-x})dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^\infty x^{-(2k+1)x}dx}$$

Using the graph again, one can use any series expansion for $e^y$ [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/06/02/) or the classic fact that $e^y= \mathop{\sum}_{x\ge 0} \frac{ y^x}{x!} $ for all real x. Desmos seems to have a hard time computing the following, but each expansion works separately which implies verifiable steps. One again can integrate term by term. Here is info on the [regularized gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/) and [exponential integral function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/) with which I would evaluate it, but the bound evaluation ends up being tricky:

$$\mathrm{I= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2k+1)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty x^n ln^n(x)dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2k+1)^n}{n!}\frac{Γ(n+1,-(n+1)ln(x)(-(n+1))^{-n}}{n+1}\bigg|_0^\infty=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)^{n-2}Q(n,nx)}{n^n (2k)!}=1.612215…<1.6180339…=\phi=\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{2}}$$

As you can see, each step was verified, but seems to be unable to find a nice form for “I” and desmos has trouble calculating the result even though I gave examples as support for the expansion of $x^{-cx}$ and sin($x^{-x}$) which still worked. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 2):

We give the following auxiliary results.

*Fact 1*: $\sin u \le u - \frac{1}{6}u^3 + \frac{1}{120}u^5$ for all $u \ge 0$.

*Fact 2*: $x^{-x} \le \frac{3 - x}{x^2 - x + 2} \le 1$ for all $x \in [1, 2]$.

*Fact 3*: $x^{-x} \le a^{-x} \mathrm{e}^{-x + a}$ for all $x, a > 0$.
(*Proof*: It is equivalent to $\ln u \ge 1 - \frac{1}{u}$ for all $u > 0$.)

---

Using Fact 1, we have (cf. Sophomore's dream)
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^1 \sin (x^{-x})\,\mathrm{d}x \\
 \le\,& \int_0^1 \left(x^{-x} - \frac16 x^{-3x} + \frac{1}{120}x^{-5x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
 =\,& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}} - \frac16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}} + \frac{1}{120}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{5^n}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}\\
 =\, & \sum_{n=0}^5 \frac{1 - 6^{-1}3^n + 120^{-1}5^n}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}
 + \sum_{n=6}^\infty \frac{1 - 6^{-1}3^n + 120^{-1}5^n}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}\\
 <\, & \sum_{n=0}^5 \frac{1 - 6^{-1}3^n + 120^{-1}5^n}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}
 + \sum_{n=6}^\infty \frac{1 - 6^{-1}3^n + 120^{-1}5^n}{7^{n + 1}}\\
 =\,& \frac{62861674901693}{65868380928000}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

---

Using Facts 1-2, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_1^2 \sin(x^{-x})\, \mathrm{d} x \\
 \le\,& \int_1^2 \sin\left(\frac{3 - x}{x^2 - x + 2}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 \le\,& \int_1^2 \left[\frac{3 - x}{x^2 - x + 2} - \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{3 - x}{x^2 - x + 2}\right)^3 + \frac{1}{120}\left(\frac{3 - x}{x^2 - x + 2}\right)^5\right]\mathrm{d}x\\
 =\,& \frac{625\sqrt7}{1029}
 \arctan\frac{\sqrt7}{5} + \frac{1687723}{18063360} - \frac12\ln 2. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

---

Using Fact 3, we have
$$\int_4^5 \sin (x^{-x})\, \mathrm{d}x
\le \int_4^5 x^{-x}\, \mathrm{d} x
\le \int_4^5 4^{-x} \mathrm{e}^{-x + 4}\, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{4 - \mathrm{e}^{-1}}{1024 + 2048\ln 2}, \tag{3}$$
and
$$\int_3^4 \sin (x^{-x})\, \mathrm{d}x
\le \int_3^4 x^{-x}\, \mathrm{d} x
\le \int_3^4 3^{-x} \mathrm{e}^{-x + 3}\, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{3 - \mathrm{e}^{-1}}{81 + 81\ln 3}, \tag{4}$$
and
$$\int_{5/2}^3 \sin(x^{-x})\,\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_{5/2}^3 x^{-x}\,\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_{5/2}^3 (5/2)^{-x}\mathrm{e}^{-x + 5/2}\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{4\sqrt{10} - 8\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}}}{125\ln \frac{5}{2} + 125}, \tag{5}$$
and
$$\int_2^{5/2} \sin(x^{-x})\,\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_2^{5/2} x^{-x}\,\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_2^{5/2} 2^{-x}\mathrm{e}^{-x + 2}\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{2 - \sqrt{2\mathrm{e}^{-1}}}{8 + 8\ln 2}. \tag{6}$$

Also, we have
$$\int_5^\infty \sin (x^{-x})\, \mathrm{d}x
\le \int_5^\infty x^{-x}\, \mathrm{d}x
\le \int_5^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x\ln 5}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{3125\ln 5}. \tag{7}$$

With the above results, we obtain the desired result
$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x^{-x})\,\mathrm{d}x < \frac{1 + \sqrt5}{2}.$$
*Note*: $(1) + (2) + (3) + (4) + (5) + (6) + (7)$ gives $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^{-x})\,\mathrm{d}x < 1.617374660$.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment we have :

### $$\int_{6}^{\infty}\sin\left(x^{-x}\right)dx+\int_{2}^{6}\sin\left(e^{\left(-\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{93}{100}}x^{0.5}\cdot2^{0.5}\ln\left(2\right)\right)}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(e^{-x\left(x-1\right)\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}+x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)dx+\int_{1}^{2}\sin\left(e^{-\left(\frac{x^{0.48}\left(x-1\right)}{2^{0.48}}\right)\cdot2\ln\left(2\right)}\right)dx-\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}{2}<0$$