# Integrate $x^{-x}$ from $0$ to infinity

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Goal: Evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^{-x} \, \text{d}x$ (by testing via calculator, the integral clearly converges).

My attempt:

$$\int_0^\infty x^{-x} \, \text{d}x = \int_0^\infty e^{-x\ln{(x)}} \, \text{d}x 
 =\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x\ln(x))^n}{n!} \, \text{d}x 
\\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty x^n(\ln(x))^n \,\text{d}x
$$

However, the integral within the sum diverges. Is there any way to simplify the integral from here, or is there another method that I’m overlooking?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this integral is expressed in an elementary closed form?

Comment: Sorry, but does this answer your question? [The "natural" Sophomore's Dream integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-x}\ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268295/the-natural-sophomores-dream-integral-int-0-infty-x-x-dx)